# Button translation & scale animation with two different title

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, translate-animation

I need to animate a button using translation and scale animation.I am using this code.Button title is "ADD MUSIC"

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3 animations:^{
    waterMarkButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
}];
```

It is transform nicely, But my title also transform, but i need title "Remove" when transform.How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can animate your title as such:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:waterMarkBduration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{

    [waterMarkButton setTitle:newText forState:UIControlStateNormal];

} completion:nil];
```

Comment: [transitionWithView:waterMarkButton setTitle:newText forState:UIControlStateNormal]; getting error that transitionWithView not declared @kunal K Shah

Comment: Yes, I already done that job. But bro, when animation finish and new title set, that time button become fade. How to remove this issue?